# Pagination issue with Single.php

Tags: theme-development, pagination, single

I am having issues understanding the worlds most simplest concept when it comes to building a single.php file and using pagination.

The code bellow shows a wordpress loop, its contents and then finally the pagination. How ever, the pagination does not show up for me and looking at twenty 10 theme shows this is how you are suppose to do it....So what's going on? This isn't a custom loop.

```
<div class="span6">
<?php 
global $post;
$thumb_nail_args = array(
    'align' => 'centered', 
    'class' => 'thumbnail marginBottom20 marginTop20'
);

if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <p>
        <em><strong>Written by: </strong>
            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>">
                <?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a>
        </em>
    </p>
    <p><?php 
    the_post_thumbnail('full', $thumb_nail_args);
    the_content(); 
    ?></p>
    <?php 
    endwhile;

    ?>
    <ul class="pager paddingBottom20">
      <li class="previous">
        <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
      </li>
      <li class="next">
        <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
      </li>
    </ul><?php 
}

if('open' == $post->comment_status){
    comments_template();
}

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link), not [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link). See the plural on the last two? The ones with the 's' are for archive pagination. The ones without it are for single post to post pagination.

Comment: I figured it was something stupid like spelling